# Request .get how to use a string as a parameter

Tags: python, rest, request, python-requests, binance

I believe it may have something to do with the **kwarg param but I have no idea how to work with that,

To specify I am trying to use the Binanace rest API to simply get the avg price for an altcoin and I can not understand how to specify which ticker to look at

Link to the specific code I’m trying to work 
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#current-average-price

Any answers would be appreciated I’m sure it will all be the same but I’m looking for the answer in python

Code:

```
binance = "https://api.binance.com"

print(requests.get(binance + "/api/v1/ticker/24hr", "BTC"))
```

Output:

```
Status code [400]
```

Expected [BTC price avg for the last 24 hour (or any numbers really)]

```
 "mins": 5,
 "price": "9.35751834"
 / or some equivalent
```

But despite me trying that and failing i am unable how to understand this api for what ever reason, i used just one before so eh,

i tried

```
print( binance + " /api/v3/ticker/price" )
```

Output:

```
Status code[200]
```

i understand that this is an success message but i do know know to how to access the data,

anyhelp would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow. It's common to post your code that didn't work, or more precisely a minimal example that reproduces the error, and say what result you expected.

Comment: Alright thank you for the input i will repost the question correctly

Comment: I think it'll be more convenient to you to edit the existing question instead of posting a new one

Comment: edited thanks, didnt see the button before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation on GitHub, you need to make a GET request with string parameter 'symbol'.
Try this code:

```
import requests
binance = "https://api.binance.com"
avg_price = "/api/v3/avgPrice"

response = requests.get(binance + avg_price + "?symbol=LTCBTC")
print(response.text)
```

This should get you output like below:

```
{"mins":5,"price":"0.00918091"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer you gave me exactly what i was looking for. Looking back now my question had two parts, and i will clarify for my self or anyone who looks back at the question

[1.] Once i got the status code 200, (which means everything was successful) it comes WITH information, I need to access that infomation 

This is done so by ".text" to the response

[2.] To put in paramiters into (at least this specific api, maybe more) is done so by "?[parameter name]= infomation" 

Thanks for your help, and i hope i personally helped anyone else as well

Comment: and also all this is pointless with the JSON module which is what i did last time